# How to insert rows using cursor in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, database-cursor

I am trying to write a function in oracle which will use cursor to insert data in one of the table. We need select query to pick the data which needs to be inserted. This is the first cursor I am writing and it turned to be too complex.

My cursor is as below:

```
/* Formatted on 11/5/2011 11:26:57 AM (QP5 v5.149.1003.31008) */
DECLARE
    CURSOR csgetpgmecultstrecrefrs (
        update_date       DATE,
        sequence_type     VARCHAR2,
        pip_number        VARCHAR2,
        startfrom         INT,
        endon             INT)
    IS
        SELECT                                   /*+first_rows(25)  parallel (PE,20) */
                pecu.component,
                 pecu.component_serial_no,
                 TO_DATE ('11/03/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     date_received,
                 TO_DATE ('11/03/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     date_programmed,
                 pecu.date_requested,
                 pecu.component_model_no,
                 pecu.product_type,
                 pecu.product_model_no,
                 pecu.product_serial_no,
                 pecu.factory_source,
                 pecu.programming_organization,
                 pecu.programming_site,
                 pecu.program_version,
                 pecu.ecu_serial_no,
                 pecu.ecu_part_no,
                 pecu.ecu_level,
                 pecu.software_assembly_id,
                 jdcp_pip_swa.pip_version software_assembly_id_upgrade,
                 TO_DATE ('11/03/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     software_upgrade_date,
                 jdcp_pip_details.released_by software_upgraded_by,
                 pecu.power_bump,
                 pecu.fuel_system_part_no,
                 pecu.fuel_pump_serial_no,
                 pecu.rack_slope,
                 pecu.off_set,
                 pecu.ecu_hours,
                 pecu.cal_file,
                 pecu.ecu_boot_block_part_no,
                 jdcp_pip_details.released_by user_id,
                 pecu.performance_option_part_no,
                 pecu.vehicle_option_part_no,
                 'PIP' sequence_type,
                 pecu.flex_power_part_no,
                 pecu.performance_option_cd,
                 pecu.vehicle_option_cd,
                 pecu.lineage,
                 pecu.replaced_by_esn,
                 pecu.replaces_esn,
                 pecu.esn_copied_from,
                 pecu.payload_seq_no,
                 pecu.vehicle_system_id,
                 pecu.user_account,
                 pecu.ecu_opcode_part_no,
                 pecu.opcode_compat_code,
                 pecu.marked_qa
          FROM   (   (  jdcp_pip_details
                            INNER JOIN
                                jdcp_pip_pin_assc
                            ON jdcp_pip_details.pip_number =
                                    jdcp_pip_pin_assc.pip_number)
                      INNER JOIN
                          jdcp_pip_swa
                      ON jdcp_pip_details.pip_swa_id = jdcp_pip_swa.pip_swa_id)
                 INNER JOIN
                     (   (SELECT pe.component,
                                     pe.component_serial_no,
                                     pe.display_serial_no_13,
                                     pe.display_serial_no_17,
                                     pe.date_requested,
                                     pe.component_model_no,
                                     pe.product_type,
                                     pe.product_model_no,
                                     pe.product_serial_no,
                                     pe.factory_source,
                                     pe.programming_organization,
                                     pe.programming_site,
                                     pe.program_version,
                                     pe.ecu_serial_no,
                                     pe.ecu_part_no,
                                     pe.ecu_level,
                                     pe.software_assembly_id,
                                     pe.power_bump,
                                     pe.fuel_system_part_no,
                                     pe.fuel_pump_serial_no,
                                     pe.rack_slope,
                                     pe.off_set,
                                     pe.ecu_hours,
                                     pe.cal_file,
                                     pe.ecu_boot_block_part_no,
                                     pe.performance_option_part_no,
                                     pe.vehicle_option_part_no,
                                     pe.flex_power_part_no,
                                     pe.performance_option_cd,
                                     pe.vehicle_option_cd,
                                     pe.lineage,
                                     pe.replaced_by_esn,
                                     pe.replaces_esn,
                                     pe.esn_copied_from,
                                     pe.payload_seq_no,
                                     pe.vehicle_system_id,
                                     pe.user_account,
                                     pe.ecu_opcode_part_no,
                                     pe.opcode_compat_code,
                                     pe.marked_qa
                              FROM programmed_ecu_13_17_map_view pe
                             WHERE pe.date_received =
                                         (SELECT /*+ INDEX_DESC(PEDR PROGRAMMED_ECU_INDEX8) */
                                                  pedr.date_received AS date_received
                                             FROM programmed_ecu pedr
                                            WHERE pedr.component_serial_no =
                                                        pe.component_serial_no
                                                    AND pedr.component = pe.component
                                                    AND (pedr.date_programmed) =
                                                             (SELECT /*+ INDEX_DESC(PEDP PROGRAMMED_ECU_INDEX8) */
                                                                      pedp.date_programmed
                                                                 FROM programmed_ecu pedp
                                                                WHERE pedp.
                                                                         component_serial_no =
                                                                            pedr.
                                                                             component_serial_no
                                                                        AND pedp.component =
                                                                                 pedr.component
                                                                        AND ROWNUM = 1)
                                                    AND ROWNUM = 1)) pecu
                      INNER JOIN
                          software_assembly_id
                      ON pecu.vehicle_system_id =
                              software_assembly_id.vehicle_system_id)
                 ON (pecu.component = jdcp_pip_pin_assc.controller_short_name)
                     AND (jdcp_pip_swa.pip_version =
                                software_assembly_id.software_assembly_id)
                     AND (pecu.component =
                                software_assembly_id.controller_short_name)
         WHERE (pecu.display_serial_no_13 = jdcp_pip_pin_assc.pin_number
                  OR pecu.display_serial_no_17 = jdcp_pip_pin_assc.pin_number)
                 AND pecu.software_assembly_id <> jdcp_pip_swa.pip_version
                 AND jdcp_pip_details.pip_number = 'TEST_FWD_ASSC'
                 AND jdcp_pip_pin_assc.status_cd NOT IN
                          ('UC', 'SU', 'FA', 'RP', 'EC')
                 AND jdcp_pip_pin_assc.forward_associated = 'N'
                 AND ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 25;

    rc   csgetpgmecultstrecrefrs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN csgetpgmecultstrecrefrs (update_date date,
                                            sequence_type varchar2,
                                            pip_number varchar2,
                                            startfrom int,
                                            endon int);
LOOP
    FETCH csgetpgmecultstrecrefrs BULK COLLECT INTO rc;

    EXIT WHEN csgetpgmecultstrecrefrs%NOTFOUND;

    INSERT
      INTO programmed_ecu (component,
                                  component_serial_no,
                                  date_received,
                                  date_programmed,
                                  date_requested,
                                  component_model_no,
                                  product_type,
                                  product_model_no,
                                  product_serial_no,
                                  factory_source,
                                  programming_organization,
                                  programming_site,
                                  program_version,
                                  ecu_serial_no,
                                  ecu_part_no,
                                  ecu_level,
                                  software_assembly_id,
                                  software_assembly_id_upgrade,
                                  software_upgrade_date,
                                  software_upgraded_by,
                                  power_bump,
                                  fuel_system_part_no,
                                  fuel_pump_serial_no,
                                  rack_slope,
                                  off_set,
                                  ecu_hours,
                                  cal_file,
                                  ecu_boot_block_part_no,
                                  user_id,
                                  performance_option_part_no,
                                  vehicle_option_part_no,
                                  sequence_type,
                                  flex_power_part_no,
                                  performance_option_cd,
                                  vehicle_option_cd,
                                  lineage,
                                  replaced_by_esn,
                                  replaces_esn,
                                  esn_copied_from,
                                  payload_seq_no,
                                  vehicle_system_id,
                                  user_account,
                                  ecu_opcode_part_no,
                                  opcode_compat_code,
                                  marked_qa
                                 )
    VALUES (
                 rc.component,
                 rc.component_serial_no,
                 rc.date_received,
                 rc.date_programmed,
                 rc.date_requested,
                 rc.component_model_no,
                 rc.product_type,
                 rc.product_model_no,
                 rc.product_serial_no,
                 rc.factory_source,
                 rc.programming_organization,
                 rc.programming_site,
                 rc.program_version,
                 rc.ecu_serial_no,
                 rc.ecu_part_no,
                 rc.ecu_level,
                 rc.software_assembly_id,
                 rc.software_assembly_id_upgrade,
                 rc.software_upgrade_date,
                 rc.software_upgraded_by,
                 rc.power_bump,
                 rc.fuel_system_part_no,
                 rc.fuel_pump_serial_no,
                 rc.rack_slope,
                 rc.off_set,
                 rc.ecu_hours,
                 rc.cal_file,
                 rc.ecu_boot_block_part_no,
                 rc.user_id,
                 rc.performance_option_part_no,
                 rc.vehicle_option_part_no,
                 rc.sequence_type,
                 rc.flex_power_part_no,
                 rc.performance_option_cd,
                 rc.vehicle_option_cd,
                 rc.lineage,
                 rc.replaced_by_esn,
                 rc.replaces_esn,
                 rc.esn_copied_from,
                 rc.payload_seq_no,
                 rc.vehicle_system_id,
                 rc.user_account,
                 rc.ecu_opcode_part_no,
                 rc.opcode_compat_code,
                 rc.marked_qa);
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!
Error message I am getting is:

> Error at line 2
>   ORA-06550: line 147, column 44:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DATE" when expecting one of the following:
>   . ( ) , * @ % & | = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not
>   range rem => ..  <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
>   and or like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ as between from using ||
>   multiset member SUBMULTISET_
>   ORA-06550: line 151, column 21:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
>   , from into bulk
>   ORA-06550: line 254, column 4:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
>   member constructor map
>   Script Terminated on line 2."

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Do you get an error? If yes, paste the exact error message? Does it not work as expected? If yes then explain in detail what you expect it to do and where your code fails.

Comment: Sorry !!! I have updated the error message in question

Comment: I still don't see a valid Oracle error message anywhere in your post

Comment: Its updated now. Please check

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your cursor is incorrect. A cursor is not declared using data types, you need to remove the whole part between the brackets. The data types for each column are determined by the columns returned by the SELECT statement:

```
CURSOR csgetpgmecultstrecrefrs 
IS
SELECT .....
```

See the examples in the manual for details:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#sthref1296

Comment: This doesn't help. There are no example with insert statement. I am looking for a insert with select statement where in one of the column is long raw. Can you provide me with such an example ?

Comment: The error you posted is all about the syntax error you have. Nowhere in your "question" you ask something about an INSERT with SELECT and RAW columns (which shouldn't be used anyway!). I answered to the question about the syntax error you posted. If you have a different question then please state it clearly.